# Ansible collections, google.cloud.gcp_storage_object, increase timeout

Tags: python, ansible, google-cloud-storage, ansible-galaxy

I am running a playbook that uses google.cloud.gcp_storage_object to upload a file to google cloud storage.
Some times this module throws timeout exception.
What I want, is to increase the timeout while calling this module but I couldn't figure out and understand why the module itself doesn't provide this parameter - unless I am missing something really obvious.

Now, first things first.
the module documentation can be found [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/google/cloud/gcp_storage_object_module.html#ansible-collections-google-cloud-gcp-storage-object-module).
I was expecting a little bit more from google to be honest. For instance, at least few more examples, but anyhow. As you can see it doesn't have any parameter for timeout.

I can see in the [repo/../gcp_storage_object.py](https://github.com/ansible-collections/google.cloud/blob/master/plugins/modules/gcp_storage_object.py) which is the source code for the module that is calling the blob.upload_from_file(file_obj). As expected, it doesn't specify the optional timeout parameter at all.
And according [Blob class documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/storage/latest/google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob#google_cloud_storage_blob_Blob_upload_from_file) it supports the timeout parameter.
(To my understanding this Class uses python requests, and python requests uses urllib3 to make the request.)

So, to recap these are my questions.
Is my understanding right? Is it possible that they have developed the ansible module without giving the option to provide custom timeout?
If no, what I am doing wrong and where should I specify the timeout?
If yes, how I could handle it in a production environment? I do not think it is proper to modify the module bymyself, what I will do everytime there is a new version of this module? Is there any professional and elegant way?

I hope all the above make sense, I am a little bit tired and cloudy at the moment.
Thank you in advance for your time! :)

Comment: "_Some times this module throws timeout exception. What I want, is to increase the timeout while calling this module_", only a hint, the error message and the circumstances under which this experienced could helpful. Just increasing a timeout value without knowing why the timeout happened could be making things more worst.

Comment: "_Why the module itself doesn't provide this parameter_", because a timeout of 60s is a long time and usually enough. "_Is it possible that they have developed the Ansible module without giving the option to provide custom timeout?_", Yes, of course.  Because a timeout of 60s is a long time and usually enough and if not, there might be something else wrong.

Comment: "_I was expecting a little bit more from google to be honest. For instance, at least few more examples_", generally for a lot of documentation could be more examples, but there would be no information gain if someone would have provided more.

Comment: "_I do not think it is proper to modify the module by myself_", why not? It is Open Source for that reason.

Comment: "_What I will do everytime there is a new version of this module?_", you would need to patch it (again) every time.

Comment: "_Is there any professional and elegant way?_", yes, of course. It would be to write a patch, propose it to the project on Github, and let if have integrated within the upstream code.

Comment: @U880D Thank you so much for taking your time to answer me all these questions! :)

Comment: @U880D I aggree that the best will be to find out why it is taking that long, but I was suspecting some temporarly network issue and I wanted to make sure that the playbook will run at the end.

Today everything seems better and run ok!

I liked the way you ansewered my questions, it gave me a different prespective, thank you.

Comment: @U880D
As a last comment, I was expecting this module to provide the option for timeout because at some point someone will need to ulpoad a large file that will take more than 60 seconds, unless I am not fully understanding the timeout concept.